# actionscript 3: how to pass array by reference to function, and have that function update it?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

ActionScript 3 passes an array by reference, by default. I must be making a rookie mistake. Here's a snapshot of my code:

```
private function testFunc():void {
    var testArray:Array=new Array();
    myFunction(testArray);
    trace(testArray); // []; length=0
}

private function myFunction(tArray:Array):void {
    tArray = myOtherFunction();
    trace(tArray); // 0, 1, 2; length=3
}

private function myOtherFunction():Array {
    var x:Array=new Array;
    for (var i:int=0; i<3; i++)
       x[i]=i;
    return x;
}
```

I can see that `tArray` is correct, but `testArray` is always empty. Any idea how to make `testArray` equal `tArray`? Thanks in advance.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00000049.html

UPDATE:

For what it's worth, I found the following change (hack) to work:

```
private function myFunction(tArray:Array):void {
    var Z:Array=new Array;
    Z = myOtherFunction();
    for (var i:int=0; i<Z.length; i++)
        tArray[i]=Z[i];
}
```

Georgii's solution is better design though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you pass testArray as a parameter to myFunction, its reference is copied and assigned to local reference tArray, such that inside of myFunction tArray points to the same object as testArray, but is in fact a different reference. That is why when you change tArray reference, testArray itself does not change.

```
private function testFunc():void {
    var testArray:Array=new Array(); 
    // testArray is a local variable, 
    // its value is a reference to an Array object
    myFunction(testArray);
    trace(testArray); // []; length=0
}

private function myFunction(tArray:Array):void {
    // tArray is a local variable, which value equals to testArray
    tArray = myOtherFunction(); 
    // now you changed it and tArray no longer points to the old array
    // however testArray inside of testFunc stays the same
    trace(tArray); // 0, 1, 2; length=3
}
```

What you probably want is:

```
private function testFunc():void {
    var testArray:Array=new Array();
    testArray = myFunction(testArray);
    trace(testArray); // 0, 1, 2; length=3
}

private function myFunction(tArray:Array):Array {
    // do what you want with tArray
    tArray = myOtherFunction();
    trace(tArray); // 0, 1, 2; length=3
    // return new value of the tArray
    return tArray;
}

private function myOtherFunction():Array {
    var x:Array=new Array;
    for (var i:int=0; i<3; i++)
       x[i]=i;
    return x;
}
```

Comment: So it sounds like its not just a reference being copied, but a new reference to a newly created Array. Good find, this isn't exactly something that pops out of Adobe's documentation.

Comment: Thanks Georgii. Well, that does work, but my point was really to find out how to do it using the original 3 functions, which is a simplified view of my real application. I can't avoid going through `myFunction()`. Any way to do that?

Comment: I'm sorry for being a pain in the butt Georgii. Yes, that works well. However, I'm already using the return in `myFunction()` for another variable (not shown for simplicity).

Comment: @ggkmath You should make better design then. Create a class MyClass that will contain tArray as a member. Then pass this class to myFunction and let it change the contents of of MyClass by assigning new value to tArray. That way you can preserve your return value.

Comment: OK, you're probably right. I'll update the original question above with another solution, although not as elegant as creating a new class...

Answer (score 2):

Basically what's happening is that you've passed your Array to the function, which in turn creates a local reference to it (within the function).

This means that if you decide to go ahead and assign a newly created Array to the local variable (`tArray` in your case), it will be used instead, and the original will retain its original instance.

This is the same for any object, for example with a Sprite:

```
var sprite:Sprite = new Sprite();

// We set the original Sprite's x to 10.
sprite.x = 10;

function mutilate(subject:Sprite):void
{
    // Notice here how we are making a new instance. This won't assign a new
    // instance to the "sprite" property that we've passed here, but rather
    // a new instance to the local variable "subject".
    subject = new Sprite();

    // And here we set the x of the new instance to 20.
    subject.x = 20;
}


mutilate(sprite);
trace(sprite.x); // Outputs 10, though you may have expected 20.
```

Comment: @ggkmath The line of concern that will prevent you from doing this is the first line in your `myOtherFunction` function. This is where you are creating a `new instance of Array` which in turn gets assigned to the local variable `tArray` within `myFunction`. There's no way to do what you're trying to do by passing the original array as an argument to a function - you will have to structure it so that what you actually do is have a function that returns the Array you expect, which you can then assign to `testArray`.

Answer (score 0):

Take the return of myOtherFunction() iterate through it and then call tArray.push() for each element. Currently all you are doing is changing a local reference to a newly created object.

You need to add elements to the original array which you lose the reference too on assignment.